# how to decode and split a string in ansible

Tags: split, ansible

I have a base64 string encoded that contains a username and password separated by a colon:

```
echo "dXNlcjpwYXNzCg==" | base64 -d
user:pass
```

and the following ansible playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  remote_user: ec2-user
  become: yes
  tasks:

  - name: echo user
    debug:
      msg:  "user: {{ 'dXNlcjpwYXNzCg==' | b64decode }}" //how to split from : and get the first value?
  - name: echo pass
    debug:
      msg:  "pass: {{ 'dXNlcjpwYXNzCg==' | b64decode }}" //how to split from : and get the second value?
```

I want to get both values to retrieve username and password from that decoded string. I know there is a split() function and I tried to do:
`{{ 'dXNlcjpwYXNzCg==' | b64decode | split(':') }}"`
but it doesn't work.

Comment: What ansible version you're running

Comment: ansible version: 2.9.9

Comment: That's good. And why not split them in your encoded string? Because what if a password has a ":" in it? Then this script will break.

Comment: because this is a simplification of a bigger playbook, in which the variables are read from a file which I don't have control of. You do have a point in that if the password contains a ":" this will break, but we do have "some sort" of control and we know that this is highly unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it.

```yaml
---
- hosts: test-multi-01
  tasks:
    - name: decode64 user and pass
      debug:
        msg:  "{{ 'dXNlcjpwYXNzCg==' | b64decode }}"
      register: user_pass

    - set_fact:
        user_and_pass: "{{ item.value.split(':') }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('dict', user_pass) }}"
      when: item.key == 'msg'

    - name: username
      debug:
        msg: "{{ user_and_pass[0] }}"

    - name: password
      debug:
        msg: "{{ user_and_pass[1] }}"
```

Gives

```sh
TASK [username] ****************************************************************************
Wednesday 16 September 2020  10:15:33 +0200 (0:00:00.057)       0:00:01.146 ***
ok: [test-multi-01] => {
    "msg": "user"
}

TASK [password] ****************************************************************************
Wednesday 16 September 2020  10:15:33 +0200 (0:00:00.040)       0:00:01.186 ***
ok: [test-multi-01] => {
    "msg": "pass\n"
}
```

Note that when the username or password contains a column `:`, the script will break.

Comment: You can remove the loop construct (`loop:` and `when:`) and use `set_fact:user_and_pass: "{{ user_pass.msg.split(':') }}"` instead